# view zip file content in tree command style

Tags: zip, tar, gzip, tree

I am seeing the zip file content using

`unzip -l files.zip | less`

but it outputs in ls style , is it possible to to display output in `tree` command style

Comment: Check this answer http://superuser.com/a/1086525/270195