# List contents of tarball in tree format

Tags: linux, tar, tree

Per the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/listing-the-content-of-a-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level) I'm able to list the contents of my tarball in `ls` format. However, I'd like to be able to list them in `tree` format, i.e. something like the latter instead of the former:

With `tar`:

```
$ tar -tf foo.tar 
foo/
foo/baz/
foo/baz/qux/
foo/baz/qux/hisfile.txt
foo/bar/
foo/bar/myfile.txt
foo/bar/yourfile.txt
```

With `tree`:

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── bar
│   ├── myfile.txt
│   └── yourfile.txt
└── baz
    └── qux
        └── hisfile.txt
```

Is it possible to do this without extracting the tarball? I'd prefer to have to avoid extracting the tarball due to their size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several scripts exist for converting a list of path names into tree form:

- my own [treeify.pl](https://nullroute.eu.org/+r/treeify)
- [treeify.rs](https://crates.io/crates/treeify/) by Loïc Damien
- [treeify.py](https://bitbucket.org/Hakril/treeify) by Hakril

All these scripts work with `tar -tf …` output; for example:

```
$ tar -tf foo.tar | treeify
foo
 ├─bar
 │  ├─myfile.txt
 │  └─yourfile.txt
 └─baz
    └─qux
       └─hisfile.txt
```

Also:

```
$ bsdtar -tf foo.zip | treeify
$ find /dir -size +5 | treeify
$ git ls-files       | treeify
$ pacman -Qql foopkg | treeify
$ unrar vb foo.rar   | treeify
$ zipinfo -1 foo.zip | treeify
$ gsettings list-schemas   | treeify -s. -f
$ qdbus | sed -n "s/^ //p" | treeify -s. -f
$ ldns-walk netbsd.org | awk '{print $1}' | treeify -s. -f -R
```

Comment: Would this script work for `.zip` as well ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: With `zipinfo -1 foo.zip` or `bsdtar -tf foo.zip`, sure.

Comment: [Found someone looking for similar help with ZIP files. Linking this post there then](http://superuser.com/questions/955750)

Answer (score 17):

This is just an addendum to user1686's answer though I do not have enough reputation to comment. While his scripts certainly do the job well they need to be downloaded while `tree` can actually do this natively:

```
$ tar tf foo.tar | tree --fromfile .
.
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   ├── myfile.txt
    │   └── yourfile.txt
    └── baz
        └── qux
            └── hisfile.txt

4 directories, 3 files
```

Note that unlike most tools `tree` uses a dot `.` and not a dash `-` to read input from stdin:

```
INPUT OPTIONS
    --fromfile
        Reads a directory listing from a file rather than the file-system.
        Paths provided on the command line are files to read from rather than directories to search.
        The dot (.) directory indicates that tree should read paths from standard input.
```

This allows one to use the typical tree functions like wildcards though sizes obviously cannot be shown and the level argument (`-L`) apparently also does not work...

Comment: Awesome! FYI this works for the output of pkgutil too: `pkgutil --payload-files OpenJDK17U-jdk_aarch64_mac_hotspot_17.0.7_7.pkg | tree --fromfile .`

Comment: Which version of `tree` is this with? My `Tree 1.7.0` by Steve Baker has no option `--fromfile`. https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Comment: I am running version 2.1.0 locally though based on the [tree manpage from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tree.1.html) it seems to be present since 1.8.0